# Catch-all Controller/Route

Tags: codeigniter

If I want to catch every single *non existing* URL that was passed to my web application and serve them a view without serving a 404, how would I do that?

Essentially I need to record the statistics based on these hits, but I need to do it by serving content and not a 404 error.

As far as I can tell from `application/config/routes.php`, I could use

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'catchall';
```

but I need that for my actual web application.

I could also use

```
$route['404_override'] = 'catchall';
```

but I don't want to throw 404s.

I tried using

```
$route['(:any)'] = '$1';
```

but I need to record the entire URL (e.g. any length of segments), not just the first segment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$route['(:any)'] = 'catchall_controller'`.  Then in your controller you can access the URI segments using `$this->uri->segment(n)`.

Comment: I wonder why this is the chosen answer, this routes all valid urls also to the catchall controller..!!

Comment: @ClainDsilva not if this route is put last. It is still something that would need a comment incase somebody tried to reorganize the routes file.

Comment: @birderic how about i want  a custom url like `http://test.com/1/folder/controller/function/param` 

*1* is dynamic ID

how will you route this? im using `CI 3.1.11` thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding multiple catch all routes for different amounts of segments?

```
$route['(:any)'] = '$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$2';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$2/$3';
```

I'm guessing that would work, but there might be a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: What about `(.+)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the difference between codeigniter and normal PHP, but, in normal php, you can edit the htaccess or whatever to define a custom 404 page.

In the custom 404 page, do something like the equivalent of this:
$requested=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

to get the URL which was requested.... do your handling... and do this to clear the 404:

header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Status: 200 OK");

Then, include your html or whatever you want to serve.

Comment: Hope you understand Codeigniter now.