# Backbone and Codeigniter - Routing problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, backbone.js

I have the same problem like its asked  here [Routing problems with Codeigniter and Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617590/routing-problems-with-codeigniter-and-backbone-js) - so, is there an existing example how this is solved? How and where do I have to adjust my code? And how do I dump Codeigniters View part and let Backbone do the complete MV part like it is suggested?

Thanks in advance...

**[UPDATE]**
So, after looking at [Catch-all Controller/Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533201/catch-all-controller-route), in my `application->config->routes.php` Do I have to add:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'catchall_controller'
```

additionally to `$route['default_controller'] = "main"` or instead of that?

then in my main Controller I have to do this or what?:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

   public function index()
   {
    $this->uri->segment(n);
    $this->load->view('home');
   }

}
```

Finally remove the `pushState:true` in my Backbone App so it says:

```
 Backbone.history.start({root: App.ROOT });
```

is this correct?

Comment: Are you using `pushState: true` when starting `Backbone.history` ?

Comment: Yes, my main.js file contains `Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: App.ROOT });`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the fact you're using pushState. From the documentation (http://backbonejs.org/#History):

> Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to
>   correctly render those pages, so back-end changes are required as
>   well. For example, if you have a route of /documents/100, your web
>   server must be able to serve that page, if the browser visits that URL
>   directly.

So your options are basically:

- stop using pushState `Backbone.history.start({ root: App.ROOT });`
- make your server return a valid response for *every* URL your Backbone app can generate (see 
  [Catch-all Controller/Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533201/catch-all-controller-route))
  You're running into issues because your client-side applications is generating URLs that your serever doesn't know how to process => 404 error

See also [Backbone router: Use hashbangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161833/backbone-router-use-hashbangs/22165652#22165652)

Comment: Ok, is there an actual example somewhere how to implement this?

Comment: If you have `Backbone.history.start({ pushState: false, root: App.ROOT });` you shouldn't need the catch all route. The options in my answer are either/or.

Comment: Yes, just use `Backbone.history.start({ root: App.ROOT });` and ignore the "catch all" route. It should work.